# Laravel5 custom RouteServiceProvider not working

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working laravel5 RouteServiceProvider stored in App/Providers. I'm not sure, if its set up right, because anyway, if I comment e.g. require app_path, it works... also if I try to put `die` inside, it doesn't do anything...
Do you have any idea, where might be problem please?
The provider is also registered in app.php:

```
'providers'=>[
'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\ViewComposerServiceProvider',
.....
]
```

Here is my RouteServiceProvider.php code.

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * This namespace is applied to the controller routes in your routes file.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        die('fadfasdfasd');
        parent::boot($router);

        //
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map(Router $router, Request $request)
    {

        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.php');
        });
    }

}



 // routes.php
    Route::post('admin/article/edit', [
        'as' => 'adminPostEditArticle',
        'uses' => 'Admin\ArticleController@postEditArticle'
    ]);
    Route::post('admin/article/create', [
        'as' => 'adminPostCreateArticle',
        'uses' => 'Admin\ArticleController@postCreateArticle'
    ]);
    Route::get('admin/article/delete/{articleId}', [
        'as' => 'adminDeleteArticle',
        'uses' => 'Admin\ArticleController@deleteArticle'
    ]);
    Route::get('admin/ajax/article/editForm/{articleId}', [
        'as' => 'adminAjaxEditArticleForm',
        'uses' => 'Admin\ArticleController@ajaxEditArticleForm'
    ]);
    Route::get('admin/ajax/article/createForm', [
        'as' => 'adminAjaxCreateArticleForm',
        'uses' => 'Admin\ArticleController@ajaxCreateArticleForm'
    ]);
    Route::get('admin/articles', [
        'as' => 'adminArticlesList',
        'uses' => 'Admin\ArticleController@index'
    ]);
```

Comment: "if I comment e.g. require app_path, it works.." - you mean routes are still loaded?

Comment: Yeah, everything still works...

Comment: Where did you put that class? Are using any opcache that could cache the previous version of the file?

Comment: Could you put the content of your `routes.php` file?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I dont know, I use clear laravel5 installation

Comment: @RomainLanz I put routes.php into my question

Comment: And where do you keep that service provider class? Did you modify the existing one or created a new one?

Comment: Its in App/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php. Its class, which was incluced in laravel5 installation